# presentModalViewController memory leak or EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access

```
-(void) addBookmarkTapped:(id)sender {
    BookmarkAddViewController *bookmarkAddViewController = 
    [[BookmarkAddViewController alloc] initWithName:currTitle link:self.addressBar.text];
    [self presentModalViewController:bookmarkAddViewController animated:YES];
    [bookmarkAddViewController release];
}
```

code above cause 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' when back to the main controller. Same error if I make bookmarkAddViewController 'autorelease'.

It will not crash if I remove the release, but it will cause memory leak?
    [bookmarkAddViewController release];

I see many examples doing the same way, why it doesn't work in my case?

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine. Your error is probably somewhere else is your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with your init method in `bookmarkAddViewController`.(Please post.) Make sure you dismiss the controller properly with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Comment: - (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name link:(NSString *)link {
    if ((self = [[BookmarkAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookmarkAddViewController" bundle:nil])) {
    self.bmName = name;
    self.bmUrl = link;
    return self;
    }
    return (id)-1;    
    }
Thanks Mundi, you helped me find the cause. It is in my init method, I set the instance variable incorrectly. It should be "bmName = name; bmUrl = link;